# LinkedIn Authentication on OWIN/MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

We've used LinkedIn OAuth/Simple membership on MVC4 project, and it is working pretty.

But with inspecting new OWIN based ASP.NET MVC5 framework, we found there is no LinkedIn authentication feature. We could use Google,Facebook,Twitter and Microsoft live ID, but no LinkedIn.

Are there any kinds of simple ways to integrate the LinkedIn authentication into new OWIN/Katana/MVC5?

Answer (score 9):

I have created providers for LinkedIn and Yahoo for use with OWIN.  Please see the blog post at http://www.beabigrockstar.com/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin/

Comment: I've just tried your linkedin OAuth on MVC5. It's working pretty. Many Thanks!

Comment: @jerrie I am using your provider for linkedin and have absolutely no issues with the login itself. However, I am trying to now use the accesstoken retrieved using login in order to make a request for some linkedin data. There is a LinkedInAuthenticatedContext class which has the AccessCode property however I am unable to figure out how to access this LinkedInAuthenticatedContext in my code. I tried to typecast it from Request.GetOwnContext but that didnt work. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone who faced the same issue I did, you can refer to Jerrie's other post which clarified the point I was stuck on. http://blog.beabigrockstar.com/get-the-twitter-profile-image-using-the-asp-net-identity/

Comment: @JohnC That differs from service to service, but generally yes it does. Here is documentation on the LinkedIn side: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token. And here is documentation on the Yahoo side: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn is currently not there in the Katana builds. We do plan to add support for LinkedIn and you will be able to get it as a Nuget package.

Comment: It's cool to get LinkedIn support. We could wait the Nuget package for that. If you could tell "When" for that, we would be happy without any custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I posted same question on Katana Project, and got an answer.

---

No immediate plans, but you might want to checkout this project:

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin

Comment: [Self responding] I'm still waiting the exact implementation.